# android: how to customize <select> popup dialog in webview

Tags: android, html, select, popup, window

I'm using html5 to develope android app. In a webpage, I use select tag, like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Using Android to browse, click the dropdown control, it will show a popup window, but I try it with serial mobile, the popup window is not same, how can I customize the style?